# Cannot clear route from DirectionRenderer ReactJS with @react-google-maps.api

Tags: reactjs, api, google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I'm trying to make a simple routing with google API and @react-google-api library, I success to show route between 2 points, but when I try to remove the route, the route cannot be removed, here's my code :

```
const calculateRoute = async () => {
    let placeServices = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    const result = await directionService.route({
      origin: {lat: -6.914864,lng: 107.608238},
      destination: {lat: -6.814864,lng: 107.608238},
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    });
    setDirection(result);
  }
```

and this my code to clear the route :

```
const clearRoute = async () => {
    setDirection(null)
  }
```

and this is my code to rendering a route :

```
 <GoogleMap
        mapContainerStyle={{
              height: '100vh',
              width: '60vw',
            }}
            zoom={14}
            center={center}
            onLoad={(map) => onLoad(map)}
          >
            {placeData.map((item, index) => (
              <MarkerF
                key={index}
                position={{
                  lat: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                  lng: item.geometry.location.lng(),
                }}
              />
            ))}
            {
              direction &&
                <DirectionsRenderer directions={direction}/>
            }
          </GoogleMap>
```

direction is a state from a useState [direction, setDirection]

Screenshot:
When route is show
[image]

When I trying to remove route
[image]

it's only reduce opacity from route

Comment: Can you provide a working codesandbox that reproduces the issue?

Comment: How did you solve the problem ? I'm getting same error ?

Comment: Seeing the same. How did you fix?

Answer (score 1):

React development mode renders twice by default. To solve this, you can remove *React StrictMode* in the *index.js* file or npm build the project as follows

```
npm install -g serve
serve -s build
```

Answer (score 0):

This post helped me uncover the answer: [How can I delete previous route on google maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33987620/how-can-i-delete-previous-route-on-google-maps)

It appears that when you use (most?) new google.maps.Whatever(), youll want to store it in a `useRef()` and use that reference throughout the life of the component.

So for example, the following is now replacing prior directions/routes when i changes the markers (which turn into origin, waypoints, destination).

It appears whenever you call `new google.maps.Whatever()`, any side-effect that might on the map persists until you call `setMap(null)` on it (which will detach it from the map, or if you reset its configuration (which is what im doing in the example below).

I was getting some oddities with the ref being "ready for use" so there might be better ways to initialize it.

```
export function MarkerMap({ markers = [] }) {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(/** @type google.maps.Map */ (null));
  const [directionsResponse, setDirectionsResponse] = useState(null);
  const directionsRenderer = useRef(
    /** @type google.maps.DirectionsRenderer */ (
      new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer()
    ),
  );
  const directionsService = useRef(
    /** @type google.maps.DirectionsService */ (
      new google.maps.DirectionsService()
    ),
  );

  useDeepCompareEffect(() => {
    async function getDirections() {
      if (directionsService?.current == null) return;

      const response = await directionsService.current.route({
        origin: markers[0],
        destination: markers[markers.length < 2 ? 0 : markers.length - 1],
        travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        optimizeWaypoints: false,
        waypoints:
          markers.length > 2
            ? markers.slice(1, -1).map((m) => ({ location: m, stopover: true }))
            : [],
      });
      setDirectionsResponse(response);
    }
    if (markers?.length > 1) {
      getDirections();
    }
  }, [markers]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!directionsRenderer?.current?.setDirections) return;

    directionsRenderer.current.setMap(map);
    directionsRenderer.current.setDirections(directionsResponse);
  }, [directionsResponse]);

  return (
    <GoogleMap
      mapContainerStyle={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
      zoom={13}
      onLoad={(map) => setMap(map)}
      onUnmount={() => setMap(null)}
    ></GoogleMap>
  );
}
```